# Tensorflow: Module must be applied in the graph it was instantiated for

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to serve universal sentence encoder with Django.

The code is initialized in the beginning as a background process (by using programs such as supervisor), then it communicates with Django using TCP sockets and eventually returns encoded sentence.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import atexit

# Pre-loading the variables:
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
atexit.register(session.close)  # session closes if the script is halted
...
# Converts string to vector embedding:
def initiate_connection(conn):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.send(session.run(embed([data])))
    conn.close()

# Process in background, waiting for TCP message from views.py
while True:
    conn, addr = _socket.accept()
    _thread = Thread(target=initiate_connection, args=(conn,))  # new thread for each request (could be limited to n threads later)
    _thread.demon = True
    _thread.start()
    conn.close()
```

But I receive the following error when executing `conn.send(session.run(embed([data])))`:

> RuntimeError: Module must be applied in the graph it was instantiated 
>   for.

---

I'm basically trying to pre-load table in tensorflow (because it takes quite a lot of time), but tensorflow doesn't let me use the session that was pre-defined.

How can I fix this? Is there any way to pre-load these variables?

P.S
I believe [this Github issue page](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/54) might have solution for my problem, but I'm not sure how could it be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Load your model with the graph that you created and use that in your session.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph = graph) as session:
     embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
```

And use the same graph object in initiate_connection function with session

```
def initiate_connection(conn):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    with tf.Session(graph = graph) as session:
        session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        conn.send(session.run(embed([data])))
    conn.close()
```